# Turn off time display in gnu screen

Tags: gnu-screen

When I'm using screen, it's really frustrating to have the clock displayed at the bottom. It updates every minute so it looks like the terminal is doing something, but it really isn't. I created my .screenrc file a while back and now it looks like line noise. My experimentation didn't get me anywhere useful.

Here's my file:

```
startup_message off
caption always '%{= kK}%{w}%H %{K}%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{B}(%{W}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{B})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{K}%{B} %{w}%c%{K}'
vbell_msg "bell: window ~%"
allpartial off
autodetach on
defscrollback 32768

# Default screens
screen -t "shell"
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove the last part with %c
See: http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/String-Escapes.html#String-Escapes

Comment: For some reason removing the last %c (with or without its surrounding color modifiers) messed up the formatting of the rest of the status line. I replaced the %c with %D (which displays the current day of the week), which seems to have "fixed" the problem. Thanks for the pointer to the manual.

Answer (score 0):

You should add: "hardstatus alwaysignore"